# Android RetroFit Refresh list

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm pretty new to RetroFit. I'd like to refresh the list when activity goes back to onResume. Scenario is like this, I'm in Activity A which has the list (retrofit), then user clicks on button which will redirect to Activity B. After Activity B is closed, list in Activity A should be refreshed. How can I achieve that?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
                RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(Constants.URL_GET_ALL_RECORDS)
                    .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .build();

                RecordsAPI api = restadapter.create(RecordsAPI.class);
                api.getRecords(new Callback<List<Record>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void success(List<Record> list, Response response) {

                        recordList = list;

                        recordadapter =
                                new DisplayAdapter(activity,
                                        R.layout.simple_spinner_item, recordList);

                        spinner.setAdapter(recordadapter);

                        if (recordadapter.getCount() == 0) {
                            lActionButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            tvNotice.setText("No records found");

                            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Intent i = new Intent(activity, ActivityB.class);
                                    activity.startActivity(i);
                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            tvNotice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                                           int pos, long id) {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                                }
                            });

                        }


                    }
                });
```

Any ideas how to refresh the list? I would gladly appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Comment: the api call you are making via api.getRecords() make a call in onresume() of the activity to get the refreshed data

Comment: @PramodYadav you mean I'll just add the whole code to onResume?

Comment: i don't think you need to do that just write the data polling part and setting it in view

Comment: @PramodYadav but this code is inside my Adapter class. How can I put them on my Activity's onResume?